# regexp: FirstName.LastName or FirstName.Letter.LastName

Tags: regex

I'd like to create a regular expression, but unfortunately my idea didn't work The regular expression should only permit the entry of a string consisting of two parts:

Part one: letters (a-z) and dot

Part two: only one letter and dot (this part isn't required but tolerable)

Part two: dot and letters (a-z)

Valid examples:

- john.shmith
- john.a.smith
- harry.x.doe
- test.y.acme

No matching examples:

- John.Smith
- John Smith
- John.A.Smith
- John.x.Smith
- John.y.smith
- Jane.y.smith.
- mary-kate.Smith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
^[a-z]+\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]+$
```

In more details:

```
^                  --->  start of match
[a-z]+\.           --->  first part (letters [a-z] and a dot)
([a-z]\.)?         --->  optional part (only one letter and a dot)
[a-z]+             --->  second part (letters [a-z])
$                  --->  end of match
```

Answer (score 0):

Part one: [a-z]+\.

Part two: ([a-z]\.)?[a-z]+